# Deploy Spring Boot 1.3.2 IBM WAS 8.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-8, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm facing a problem deploying a simple spring boot web on IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 using full profile

WAS is by default using servlet 3.0 and java 1.7.

The application does not do much, just display a page with a "Hi - [current-date]".

When deploying the war file, we see the following in server log output:

```
[2/3/16 13:30:44:857 AST] 00000078 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the simpledemo_war application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wps_admin)
[2/3/16 13:30:44:871 AST] 00000078 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=simpledemo_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=simpledemo_war.
[2/3/16 13:30:44:958 AST] 00000078 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: simpledemo_war
[2/3/16 13:30:44:959 AST] 00000078 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0203I: Application: simpledemo_war  Application build level: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[2/3/16 13:30:46:347 AST] 00000078 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: simpledemo.war.
[2/3/16 13:30:46:356 AST] 00000078 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
[2/3/16 13:30:46:357 AST] 00000078 InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:490)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:605)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessor.java:548)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessor.java:716)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorContextImpl.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessorContextImpl.java:61)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processAnnotations(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:741)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:561)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.SharedInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(SharedInjectionEngineImpl.java:229)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(ReferenceContextImpl.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:390)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.populateJavaNameSpace(WebAppImpl.java:1112)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:328)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
        at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
        at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
        at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
        ... 120 more

[2/3/16 13:30:46:388 AST] 00000078 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/simpledemo
[2/3/16 13:30:52:873 AST] 00000078 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [simpledemo_war#simpledemo.war]:.Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@fcdf38eb]
[2/3/16 13:30:52:874 AST] 00000078 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module null has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].
[2/3/16 13:30:52:889 AST] 00000078 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: simpledemo_war
[2/3/16 13:30:52:889 AST] 00000078 CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=simpledemo_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=simpledemo_war started.
```

Spring boot does not seem to start, I'm not seeing anything in the logs to indicate that my servlet is being initialized.
I'm using spring boot with maven and java 1.7. I don't have web.xml file in the war.
Here is my Boot Application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSimpleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSimpleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Project POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>simple-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE-1:**
I have followed Spring guide on deploying to external containers, the same war works on JBoss EAP 6.2 and tomcat 8

**UPDATE-2:**
added a new class (I don't know how I forgot it) that extends SpringBootServletInitializer and removed spring-boot-devtools from POM, See Andy Wilkinson answer..

Comment: How u made it works ? i guess you not starting the websphere server using this Spring main method, so you calling the method from another place after the server loaded , or something else ? was required to add some additional configuration using WAS console website ? tnx a lot for any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can safely ignore the warning messages from WAS. They're rather noisy but they won't stop your application from starting successfully.

The problem appears to be that you don't have a `SpringBootServletInitializer` in your application. If you did, it would have been listed in this log message:

```
[2/3/16 13:30:52:873 AST] 00000078 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [simpledemo_war#simpledemo.war]:.Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@fcdf38eb]
```

The easiest way to provide one is to update `DemoSimpleApplication` to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override its configure method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSimpleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoSimpleApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSimpleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I have added that and I faced a new Problem due to POM file contained dependency spring-boot-devtools, I removed that and it works fine

Comment: Devtools is the worst you can have on your production server, it is solely there for development

Comment: I don't know why I even added it!