# Unable to start Sprint application in Websphere 8.x

Tags: spring, websphere, websphere-8

We have an application which is perfectly working in our Websphere QA region but when shipped to the clients they reported below startup errors.

We have already verified the class-loaders settings. They are correct (parent last).

What could be the possible issue here? Any hint will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
[1/12/18 14:43:55:529 AEDT] 000000a9 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: my-test-app.war.
[1/12/18 14:43:55:550 AEDT] 000000a9 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
[1/12/18 14:43:55:552 AEDT] 000000a9 InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:283)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:819)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessor.java:548)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessor.java:716)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorContextImpl.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessorContextImpl.java:61)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processAnnotations(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:741)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:561)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.SharedInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(SharedInjectionEngineImpl.java:229)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(ReferenceContextImpl.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:390)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.populateJavaNameSpace(WebAppImpl.java:1377)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:328)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1383)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:972)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:777)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1380)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2191)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:292)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1261)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:422)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:92)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1255)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1093)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:832)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
       at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$QueuedWork.run(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1987)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:786)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:764)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
        ... 62 more


[1/12/18 14:43:55:589 AEDT] 000000a9 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key VHRLSLF/
[1/12/18 14:45:21:521 AEDT] 000000a9 MyFacesContai I   Added FacesServlet with mappings=[/faces/*, *.jsf, *.faces]
[1/12/18 14:45:21:677 AEDT] 000000a9 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT#my-test-app.war]:.2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[1/12/18 14:45:23:016 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[1/12/18 14:45:23:017 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[1/12/18 14:45:23:033 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)
[1/12/18 14:45:23:033 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O
[1/12/18 14:45:25:209 AEDT] 000000a9 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT#my-test-app.war]:.Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[1/12/18 14:45:31:273 AEDT] 000000a9 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application my-test-app.war
[1/12/18 14:45:31:285 AEDT] 000000a9 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, my-test-app.war, of application, RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT.ear/deployments/RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT, failed to start
[1/12/18 14:45:31:300 AEDT] 000000a9 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT
[1/12/18 14:45:31:301 AEDT] 000000a9 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT
[1/12/18 14:45:31:349 AEDT] 000000a9 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT
[1/12/18 14:45:31:367 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
[1/12/18 14:45:31:367 AEDT] 000000a9 SystemOut     O WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
[1/12/18 14:45:31:381 AEDT] 000000a9 CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT in BLA WebSphere:blaname=RLSSATSIT7C1_SAT failed to start.
```

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238178/deploy-spring-boot-1-3-2-ibm-was-8-5

Comment: I saw that post and can confirm we already have the correct SprintBootServletInitializer setup as suggested in that solution